# Android MP3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Tags: android, resources, audio

I am trying to play a custom sound `res/raw/notification.mp3`. It is ~91KB.

Here is my code

```
MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.notification).start();
```

Here is my error

```
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/notification.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:860)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at mypackage.MyActivity$1.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:123)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:426)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:857)
04-14 15:57:55.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(233):     ... 14 more
```

Same thing happens to an unrelated WAV file so it is probably not the MP3's problem.

What might be wrong? Should I uncompress the WAV/MP3? How?

Comment: I think you don't need file extension while opening.

Comment: Solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with the NetBeans generated build scripts. I did a tutorial from scratch and it failed in NetBeans and worked in Eclipse. I suppose I will finally learn Eclipse. It is something I have been wanting to do at least as a comparison in hopes it would be less buggy, but I have not had the time. Well necessity is going to gave me the time now.

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing for the context value?  Context is used to know where to look for the resource file.  It looks like you may have called this inside an AsyncTask? Are you using `getApplicationContext()` to get a reference?  For instance, if this code were inside an Activity, you would call this method as:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.notification).start();
```

If not, you need to pass a proper context that maps to your application package.

Another possibility is your R.java is out of date.  Make sure your XML files don't have any errors keeping aapt from rebuilding the resources, and maybe run a Clean on the project.

Another thing you could try is to place your MP3 file into the assets directory and try to load the sound this way.  For a file located at `assets/notification.mp3`:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("notification.mp3");
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
afd.close();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Try this in an Activity first, as `getAssets()` needs to be called from a Context.  This method circumvents issues that may be occuring in the resources bundle and may better determine where the true culprit is.

Hope that helps!

Comment: **a)** I have tried placing the line of code in an `Activity`'s `onResume` using `this` in place of `context`. I have also tried the line of code in a `new ASyncTask` that is created in `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)` method in which case the `onReceive` parameter `context` is made final and used in the anonymous subclass of `ASyncTask`. Both ways fail with the same error. . **b)** (in NetBeans IDE) I just did clean, emptied out `R.java`, clean/build (rebuilds `R.java`), another (wasted) clean/build and then run and it still fails with the same error.

Comment: Same thing happens to unrelated WAV file so it is probably not the MP3's problem

Comment: Updated with a method using the assets directory as another test.