# java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Tags: java, android, cordova, filenotfoundexception

i am programming a soundboard from android.
the problem is that some sounds works, and some dont work.
here is the traceback that i get for the sounds that doesnt work

```
05-31 13:23:04.227 18440 18603 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
05-31 13:23:04.227 18440 18603 W System.err:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)
05-31 13:23:04.227 18440 18603 W System.err:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:331)
05-31 13:23:04.227 18440 18603 W System.err:    at com.phonegap.AudioPlayer.startPlaying(AudioPlayer.java:201)
05-31 13:23:04.227 18440 18603 W System.err:    at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.startPlayingAudio(AudioHandler.java:181)
05-31 13:23:04.235 18440 18603 W System.err:    at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:64)
05-31 13:23:04.235 18440 18603 W System.err:    at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:86)
05-31 13:23:04.235 18440 18603 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a limitations on opening compressed files in the assets folder. This is because uncompressed files can be directly memory mapped into the processes virtual address space, therefore avoiding needing the same amount of memory again for decompression.

[Dealing with Asset Compression in Android Apps](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/) discusses some techniques in dealing with compressed files. You can trick `aapt` into not compressing the file by using an extension that is not compressed (e.g. `mp3`) or you can manually add them to the `apk` without compression instead of getting `aapt` to do the work.

Comment: Finally, an answer to all of my problems. This is really poorly documented! +1

Comment: The binary asset file I have is around 1.1MB. I renamed it to jpg/png etc so that the compression does not kick in. But when copied to the sdcard, it swells up to ~8MB. So somehow, AssetManager still thinks that it needs to be uncompressed. Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: After wasting a few hours, I finally managed to read the files off of raw instead of assets and they are not 'uncompressed' any more.

Comment: It'd be nice if there were a list of the extensions that aren't compressed :-P

Comment: @GreenBee would you mind pointing out how to copy a file from the raw directory? I've tried adding the noCompress option, for a concrete extension, and copying the file (bigger than 1MB) but nothing is working. I get the size of the APK in the copied file. Strange :S

Answer (score 118):

You can disable asset compression for certain extensions like so:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "pdf"
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic)

Comment: in my case there was a zip already in assets folder.
So it compressed the file once again while compilation.
I have  put "zip" instead of "pdf" and the error gone.

Comment: You can verify which entries are compressed with this command:

`unzip -lv MyApplication.apk`

'Stored' in the 'Method' column means the file is not compressed.

Comment: You saved me from banging my head against the wall :D Thank you very much!

Comment: Worked for me, i had an .xml file. Once i added it to noCompress all worked fine, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, man, this has been bugging me for weeks. For some reason I could not play ogg files anymore. I didn't touch my code or my phone, I only updated Android Studio. Glad to have found this answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 53):

People working with Tensorflow Lite file running into this issue,

Add the following lines to your Gradle file (`android/app/build.gradle`) inside the `android{}` block.

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
```

Comment: It is Ok on sample project. But when i compile aar, this error happens in aar mode in new project.

Answer (score 13):

You should disable compression for that file. Simply add:

```
    aaptOptions {
       noCompress "your-file-name"
    }
```

To your app level `build.gradle` file inside `android { }`

Answer (score 5):

This decidedly irritating situation comes about because when the `.apk` is built, some assets are compressed before storing them, whereas other are treated as already compressed (e.g. images, video) and are left alone. The latter group can be opened using `openAssetFd`, the former group can't - if you try, you get the "This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed" error.

One option is to trick the build system into not compressing the assets (see the link in @nicstrong's answer), but this is fiddly. Better to try and work around the problem in a more predictable fashion.

The solution I cam up with uses the fact that while you can't open an `AssetFileDescriptor` for the asset, you can still open an `InputStream`. You can use this to copy the asset into the application's file cache, and then return a descriptor for that:

```
@Override
public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(final Uri uri, final String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final String assetPath = uri.getLastPathSegment();  // or whatever

    try
    {
        final boolean canBeReadDirectlyFromAssets = ... // if your asset going to be compressed?
        if (canBeReadDirectlyFromAssets)
        {
            return getContext().getAssets().openFd(assetPath);
        }
        else
        {
            final File cacheFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), assetPath);
            cacheFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            copyToCacheFile(assetPath, cacheFile);
            return new AssetFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(cacheFile, MODE_READ_ONLY), 0, -1);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void copyToCacheFile(final String assetPath, final File cacheFile) throws IOException
{
    final InputStream inputStream = getContext().getAssets().open(assetPath, ACCESS_BUFFER);
    try
    {
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile, false);
        try
        {
            //using Guava IO lib to copy the streams, but could also do it manually
            ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream); 
        }
        finally
        {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

This does mean that your app will leave cache files lying about, but that's fine. It also doesn't attempt to re-use existing cache files, which you may or may not care about.

Answer (score 5):

This exception can be thrown by calling:

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd = activity.getAssets().openFd(path);
```

I fixed the problem by saving the file in `res/raw` directory instead of assets folder, then get the `AssetFileDescriptor` this way:

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd = activity.getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawId);
```

Then the `FileNotFoundException` is gone, and the file is not compressed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You should get this exception only if trying to open the `FileDesriptor`. For just reading the file you can go the way through the `InputStream` (`AssetManager.open("filename.ext")`). This worked for me.

If you need the file size in advance, you need the `FileDescriptor` (and therefore an uncompressed file) to call its `getLength()` method, otherwise you have to read the whole stream to determine its size.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a walk around, I use:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(file).getParcelFileDescriptor();
```

But that return: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed.

Instead of this implementation I open the file directly using functions form ParcelFileDescriptor.

```
private void openRenderer(Context context,String fileName) throws IOException {  

File file=  FileUtils.fileFromAsset(context, fileName);
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE); 

        mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
    }`

    public class FileUtils {
    private FileUtils() {
    }

    public static File fileFromAsset(Context context, String assetName) throws IOException {
        File outFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), assetName );
        copy(context.getAssets().open(assetName), outFile);

        return outFile;
    }

    public static void copy(InputStream inputStream, File output) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            boolean read = false;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            int read1;
            while((read1 = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if(inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if(outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `kotlin dsl` it would look like this:

```
    androidResources {
        noCompress.add("tflite")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just added the extension of my file like below in the build.gradle and solved my issue

```
android {
   aaptOptions {
      noCompress "tflite"
      noCompress "txt"
      noCompress "pdf"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file to be obtained from the assets folder is bigger than 1MB, then what has worked for me is to compress the file as a zip file, then unzip it before using it, and store it in the external storage uncompressed.

```
InputStream fileInputStream = getAssets().open("your_file.your_file_extension.zip");
unzipInputStream(fileInputStream, "your_folder_in_external_storage");
```

The `unzipInputStream` method I've used is this one:

```
public static void unzipInputStream(InputStream inputStream, String location)
{
    try {
        if ( !location.endsWith(File.separator) ) {
            location += File.separator;
        }
        File f = new File(location);
        if(!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, BUFFER_SIZE));
        try {
            ZipEntry ze;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String path = location + ze.getName();
                File unzipFile = new File(path);

                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    if(!unzipFile.isDirectory()) {
                        unzipFile.mkdirs();
                    }
                } else {
                    createParentDirectoriesIfMissing(unzipFile);
                    unzipFile(zin, unzipFile);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            zin.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "Unzip exception", e);
    }
}

private static void createParentDirectoriesIfMissing(File unzipFile)
{
    File parentDir = unzipFile.getParentFile();
    if ( null != parentDir ) {
        if ( !parentDir.isDirectory() ) {
            parentDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}

private static void unzipFile(ZipInputStream zin, File unzipFile) throws IOException
{
    int size;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(unzipFile, false);
    BufferedOutputStream fout = new BufferedOutputStream(out, BUFFER_SIZE);

    try {
        while ( (size = zin.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1 ) {
            fout.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }

        zin.closeEntry();
    } finally {
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, because the *gnome-sound-recorder* creates OGG files, which I can't play using the MediaPlayer. So I converted them to MP3 with *ffmpeg* and it worked. So I guess this is the easiest way.

```
ffmpeg -i youroggfile yournewfile.mp3
```

What I also noticed is that it does still show up with a question mark in the resources and that when I access it with **R.raw.yournewfile** I do not write the ".mp3" extension in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and I copy the file from res/raw to /data/data/your.app.pkg/cache folder, then everything go well :D

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
try {
    File cache = new File(getCacheDir(), "my_data.dat");
    if (!cache.exists()) {
        copyInputStreamToFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_data), cache);
    }
    afd = new AssetFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(cache, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY), 0, AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


private void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) {
    BufferedOutputStream bfos = null;

    try {
        bfos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            bfos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bfos != null) {
                bfos.close();
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it caused by resource.arsc is compressed. Rebuilding with uncompressed resource.arsc solve the problem.