# This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Tags: android

I get the error:

```
This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
```

After some googling it appears that I need to add an extension to my file, such as .mp3, the only problem is, my file is already an mp3.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: where do u put your file? u should put your mp3 file in `xml/raw` folder.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor

Answer (score 4):

add following to build.gradle file

```
   aaptOptions {
       noCompress "mp3"
   }
```