# openRawResourceFd fails on android

Tags: android, file-descriptor, android-assets

I'm writing my first Android application, and I'm trying to read a `res/raw` resource file.

The following code `throws` a `FileNotFound` Exception:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.myfile);
```

but this line of code works:

```
InputStream stream = res.openRawResource (R.raw.myfile);
```

I need the `AssetFileDescriptor` in order to determine the length of the file.  Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: did you find any way to do this??

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
FileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.rawResourceId).getFileDescriptor();
```

No try/catch block required.

Answer (score 0):

Move your myfile to asset folder and try this

```
try{
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd( "myfile" );
    FileDescriptor fd = descriptor.getFileDescriptor();
}
catch(Exception)
{

}
```

Or you can try to open a RAW file from the resources/raw foder with this code:

```
FileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.myfile).getFileDescriptor();
```

Comment: This is not the permanent solution, as in asset folder i am getting file is compressed error for which i need to put file in raw directory only see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor

Comment: openRawResource returns Inputstream and not FileInputStream

Answer (score 0):

This works;

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.rawResourceId);
```