# How do I read the Android Manifest without using PackageManager?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

I am working on an Android application that requires more information than what is available in the `PackageManager` (such as *intent filters*). I have created a parser for reading the AndroidManifest file, but I cannot find the location of the `AndroidManifest.xml` for any installed application. The code I am using is:

```
int flags = PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES
                       //| PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS
                       //| PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS
                       //| PackageManager.GET_GIDS
                       //| PackageManager.GET_INSTRUMENTATION
                       //| PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS //Not needed (see BUG: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217)
                       | PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
                       | PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
                       | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS
                       | PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS
                       | PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER
                       | PackageManager.GET_SERVICES
                       | PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES
                       | PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
                       | PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES
                       | PackageManager.GET_URI_PERMISSION_PATTERNS;
final PackageInfo pkg = pm.getPackageInfo(info.packageName, flags);
File manifest = new File(pkg.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
if (manifest.exists()) {
    //Code never reaches this point
}
```

According to the documentation, [ApplicationInfo.publicSourceDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#publicSourceDir) is:

> Full path to the location of the publicly available parts of this
>   package (i.e. the primary resource package and manifest). For
>   non-forward-locked apps this will be the same as {@link #sourceDir).

What am I doing wrong, or how can I do this right?

Comment: I suppose that manifest are stored in dex archive. Can you see what files are in `pkg.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir`?

Comment: @Jin35, when I did `new File(pkg.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir).list()`, it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a long time, but I figured it out. Assets, such as the manifest, are compressed - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor/6187097#comment10641527_6187097). If it had not been compressed, the code provided by @gwa (or something similar to it) would have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here the code:

```
AssetManager am = yourContext.createPackageContext("packageName", 0).getAssets();

XmlResourceParser xml = am.openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");
```

but then you need to parse it.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Do you have an example of this code in context?

Comment: I use this code in my app for reading the 'installLocation' attribute, it works well. What happens with you?

Comment: I get a `FileNotFoundException`, which is strange since `am.list()` displays the *AndroidManifest.xml*, along with a few other assets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your app have enough privilege to read it. Try it on an rooted device.