# Phonegap Media error code 1 playing local mp3 file in Android device

Tags: android, cordova, mp3, media

I developing an app that play a local mp3 file.

When I run in the app with the MOTODEV Studio in the emulator and in
my phone it works perfectly.

But when I upload to Google Play Market, and install the app in other
phone, it sends me this error

"Error code 1 , message undefined"

The error log is

```
03-15 22:12:58.364 D/skia    ( 2275): >>>>>> Touch event handled. action:2; preventDefault=0 .{193,192}
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:314)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at com.phonegap.AudioPlayer.startPlaying(AudioPlayer.java:215)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.startPlayingAudio(AudioHandler.java:233)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:78)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:150)
03-15 22:12:58.473 W/System.err( 2275): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-15 22:12:58.520 D/skia    ( 2275): >>>>>> Touch event handled. action:1; preventDefault=0 .{193,192}
03-15 22:12:58.536 D/skia    ( 2275): >>>>>>>: CacheBuilder::BuildFrame(()
03-15 22:12:58.543 D/skia    ( 2275): >>>>>>> WebViewCore::updateFrameCache()--2--cachedFocusNode=1; (nodePointer=0x670b90); m_frameCacheKit=0x34e560; m_updatedFrameCache=1
```

Thanks

Comment: is there a full error log you could post?

Comment: How can I get this full error log?

Comment: If you have the Android developer tools installed then `adb logcat` from a shell (or use the Log from Eclipse if you have that setup) otherwise you could install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat on your device and look for errors in there.

Comment: Ok. There's an error. The log is in the original question

Comment: Are you sure that the file you want to play is in the .apk you created?

Comment: Yes. in /android_asset/www/bap.mp3

Comment: I don't see why that would happen if your file is a `.mp3` but there are similar problems to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor