# Android: getAssets().openFd() and FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-assets

I am trying to read a txt file from assets folder like that:

```
descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd("openAccess.txt");
reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

but I am getting this exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file
>   descriptor; it is probably compressed

I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor)

Comment: ana,try using `AssetFileDescriptor`

Comment: @imrankhan, how to use it? Thank you.

Comment: See me comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor/31425092#31425092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("openAccess.txt");
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor()));
String line = f.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // do stuff
    Log.d("TAG",line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("openAccess.txt");
reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
```

Comment: Still the same problem @David Wasser

Comment: Are you sure that the text file is actually present in your assets?

Comment: Oh, it works now, sorry, i did a litle mistake. The other problem now is that I am getting the file adress like java.io.InputStreamReader@405248a0

Answer (score 1):

What did it for me was to create a "row"-folder in /res and to copy the files in there.
Then you can use:

```
InputStreamReader iReader = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. File Path.

```
context.getAssets().openFd("file:///android_asset/openAccess.txt");
```

Comment: still the same problem: fileNotFoundException

Comment: Please check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor

Answer (score 0):

you can create new folder in Asset and place your file in that folder and try to get that file from this folder