# How do I reference this TFLite file in my Flutter App

Tags: tensorflow, flutter, visual-studio-code

I need to reference my TFLite model and the labels in my flutter app:

```
  static Future<String> loadModel() async {
    AppHelper.log("loadModel", "Loading model..");

    return Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/model_unquant.tflite", //HERE
      labels: "assets/labels.txt", //AND HERE
    );
  }
```

Right now I keep getting this exception:

```
E/MethodChannel#tflite(29061): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/./assets/model_unquant.tflite
```

What's the right way for me to reference these files? My filing is as follows:

```
Project Folder
-> Assets
   -> labels.txt
   -> model_unquant.tflite
-> lib
   -> File where I assign the model
```

It works in this guy's project: https://github.com/umair13adil/tensorflow_lite_flutter/blob/master/lib/helpers/tflite_helper.dart, but it won't work for mine. I believe the only difference to be versions but they are not wildly different (this project was published this March)

Edit: I am using the latest versions of everything, Tflite, flutter, and the Camera plugin for flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add tffile in pubspec.yaml file

```
  assets:
    - assets/model_unquant.tflite
    - assets/labels.txt
```

Comment: That worked, I should have paid more attention to documentation! Thank you! After I did this I got a new error saying the file is compressed - anyone else having the same issue  please follow the instructions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249432/13758089